# Placing Additional Legend at the bottom of existing legend in R

Tags: r, plot

I have the following legend:

[image]

How can I locate the center text with "Mean and SD" so that 
it can be placed exactly under "---emp".?

The code that generate that is this:

```
L = list(bquote(Em.Mean ==.(new_avg)),
    bquote(Em.SD==.(new_std)), bquote(Th.Mean ==.(theor_avg)),
    bquote(Th.SD==.(theor_sd)))

legend("topright", c(kids,"emp."), cex=0.7, bty="n", col=c(cm.colors(6), "red"),
    pch=c(rep(19, 6), -5), lty = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0), )

# How can I locate this    
legend("topcenter", cex=0.5, bty="n", legend=sapply(L, as.expression))
```

Comment: When you post code it is advisable that you clean it up so it's more readable rather than trying to mash everything together using semicolons and no spaces.  Additionally, providing a reproducible example makes it more likely that you'll get a response that you're after.

Comment: To answer your question you may want to use `locator()` to determine coordinates of the 2nd legend.  Note that `legend` takes coordinate arguments for placement.  `?legend`

Comment: `legend` invisibly returns a list with a `rect` component that contains width (`w`), height (`h`), left (`left`), and top (`top`) components -- you can use these to compute the location of the bottom-center of the legend box. (This is described in the `Value` section of `?legend`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`legend` coordinates can be assigned to an object. These coordinates can then be used to place you second legend. For example,

```
x <-10:1
y <-11:20
plot(x,y,type="h")
my.legend.size <- legend("topright",c("Series1","Series2","Series3"))
> my.legend.size
$rect
$rect$w
[1] 1.599609

$rect$h
[1] 1.506977

$rect$left
[1] 8.760391

$rect$top
[1] 20.36


$text
$text$x
[1] 9.266641 9.266641 9.266641

$text$y
[1] 19.98326 19.60651 19.22977
```

Using $rect$left,$rect$top and $rect$h, you can provide new coordinates for the second legend.

```
#second legend
legend(x=my.legend.size$rect$left,y=my.legend.size$rect$top-    
my.legend.size$rect$h,c("Series4","Series5","Series6"))
```

[image]

I noticed that the width of your second legend is bigger than the first one. The trick here is to get the coordinates of the second legend but not printing it using `,plot = FALSE` The x coordinate of the second legend is `my.legend.size2$rect$left`.

```
x <-10:1
y <-11:20
plot(x,y,type="h")
my.legend.size <-legend("topright",c("Series1","Series2","Series3"))
my.legend.size2 <-legend("right",c("Long series name","Series5","Series6"),plot = FALSE)
legend(x=my.legend.size2$rect$left,y=my.legend.size$rect$top-
my.legend.size$rect$h,c("Long series name","Series5","Series6"))
```

[image]

PS: I have left the boxes around the legends to show that placement is perfect, but you can remove them using `bty = "n"`